# Specific gradle options for target build platform

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, cross-platform

I have a Kotlin project (not Android) that uses the LWJGL library. Under macOS, I need to add the following options to `build.gradle`:

```
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-macos"
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-XstartOnFirstThread"]

dependencies {
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom')
    implementation platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3")
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal"

    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal::$lwjglNatives"
}
```

On Windows, however, I need to drop `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`, and set `lwjglNatives` to:

```
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-windows"
```

How can I tell gradle to do this? Basically I need some kind of target platform check.

Moreover, I need to know the target platform in Kotlin was well. How can I tell the build platform from Kotlin code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The operating system can be tested like this:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-windows"
} else {
    project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-macos"
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-XstartOnFirstThread"]
}
```

To access this from Kotlin, a `BuildConfig.java` needs to be generated ad hoc:

```
tasks.register('generateSources') {
    ext.outputDir = "$buildDir/generated/java"
    outputs.dir outputDir
    doFirst {
        mkdir "$outputDir/ch/digorydoo/ksoundrender"
        file("$outputDir/ch/digorydoo/ksoundrender/BuildConfig.java").text =
                """|package ch.digorydoo.ksoundrender;
               |public class BuildConfig {
               |    public static Boolean isWindows() {
               |        return ${if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) "true" else "false"};
               |}
               |}""".stripMargin()
    }
}

compileKotlin.dependsOn generateSources
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir generateSources.outputDir
```

Now I can just import `BuildConfig` from Kotlin.